# Cloud foundry: Uses of manifest v/s cf command

Tags: ibm-cloud, manifest, cloud-foundry, devops

Typically manifest contains deployment concerns which are specific to environments. Those concerns can also be met using cf commands. Given a choice of using manifest v/s cf to define scale, bindings, number of instances ... etc, which one would you recommend. In the DevOps based world of cloud applications, do application developers also need to address deployment concerns?

Answer (score 1):

manifest.yml is preferably used if you have a large number of deployments ie. to save you from repetitive task of configuring the app again and again after deployment.

In the cloud world the gap between administrators and developers is getting smaller. This means that developers should be more involved in the process of deployment and especially in process of monitoring application performance in order to improve it.